# Accessing TSQL created #temp tables from CLR stored procedure. Is it possible?

Tags: t-sql, sqlclr, temp-tables

1. I have a TSQL Stored Procedure **tsql__sp__A** which does two things:

(a) Creates a temp table **#tempTable** that has SELECT data from a complex SELECT query.

(b) Calls a CLR managed Stored Procedure **clr__sp__B** for each row that does computation on row parameters.

Question: Is it possible to access **#tempTable** from CLR procedure **clr__sp__B**  using the same connection context? (No, I don't want to move or create another **#tempTable** inside managed procedure)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Boj.

However I found that when you use with a "context connections=true" it opens up all the SET

[Read Bol Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345135(SQL.90).aspx#mandataac_topic5)

//The context connection lets you execute SQL statements in the same context that your code was invoked in the first place//

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
{
    connection.Open();
    // access #temp table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define two types of temp tables in SQL.

- local
- global

About local temp tables:

> When table is preceded by single ‘#’ sign, it is defined as local temporary table and its scope is limited to session in which it is created.

And about global temp tables:

> In contrast of local temporary tables, global temporary tables are visible across entire instance.

So may you should try using "##" to create a global temp table. (*If* there is a difference between "connection context" and "session")

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have global temp tables (##) as a last option but was wondering if there is a way to pass the current session/connection context of TSQL to manager CLR?

Comment: Huh, good question. But whats about inversion of calls? I mean you create a managed "wrapper" stored procedure, and that procedure calls  tsql__sp__A and after that clr__sp__B. Or, you rewrite clr__sp__B to call tsql__sp__A first.